# In JQuery ajax, how do I handle a HTTP 408 error properly?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I do a JQuery Ajax call with the "error" option set. In my "error" method I would like to handle an HTTP 408 differently from a normal HTTP 500.

The problem is that the jxhr.statusCode is 0 and the "status" value is simply "error"! But in firebug I can see that the service definitely returned status code 408.

Why would the jxhr.statusCode be 0?  Is there another way to identify an HTTP 408 error?

My error handler code looks as follows (for a 408 error the code just continues into the 'else' block):

```
error: function (jxhr, status, error) {
var $message = element.next().find('.loadmask-msg-label');
if (jxhr.status == 401)
  $message.html(settings.unauthorizedMessage);
else if (jxhr.status == 408)
  $message.html(settings.timeoutMessage);
else
  $message.html(settings.errorMessage);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was FIREFOX. In any browser except Firefox the status code is 408. In Firefox the status code is 0, and no response headers are returned. Also, Firefox seems to re-request 10 times because of the 408 response, I have no idea why! And this is only for an HTTP 408 response.

In the end we had to return a HTTP 500 error with custom headers.

Dirty :(

Comment: I have encounted this issue as well. My server returned an expected 408 and Firefox just kept trying the request over again. I have since opened a bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=907800

Comment: Still seems to be the case that Firefox handling of 408 is faulty in that it rejects with status code 0 and no parsing of request on the first request that causes 408. On subsequent requests to same url the request is rejected with 408 as it should be.

Answer (score 3):

According to Jquery you should do this :

[image]

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
})
```

;

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid my code still goes into the 0: section instead of the 408: section :(

Comment: @willem did you consider by checking the text instead of code ?

Comment: I did. The 'status' text was 'error'. And the 'error' text was ''. Not sure what else there is to check :(